# SharePoint 2010 Change Require Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've added the following code to a SharePoint page - code finds the requested **select** based on **title** and alerts when "**Decision**" **value** is selected.

Looking to remove the alert and replace with code which finds a specific **select** (title$=test) and changes it to mandatory/required.

How do you so with SP2010?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Deploy/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Deploy/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[title$='Based on']").change(function() {
        var text = $("select[title$='Based on'] :selected").text();
        if (text == "Decision") {
            alert('you must provide reason for suspending this order');
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do validation on a form field it looks like your best bet is to hook into the `PreSaveAction` method as per this [article](http://ghamson.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/useful-javascript-function-presaveaction-sp2010-sharepoint-ps2010-projectserver-in/) by Giles Hamson.  Inside of your change event you could do the following to mark your field as required:

```
$("select[title$='test']").attr('required','true');
```

Then, inside of your `PreSaveAction` method you could check if the dropdown is required and also if it has a value.  Using that you could allow the save to continue or you could stop it and display a validation error.

```
function PreSaveAction() 
{
    var dropdown = $("select[title$='test']");

    if(dropdown.attr('required') == 'true' && dropdown.val() == "")
    {
        alert("The field 'test' is required'");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should of been clearer. I'm looking for the dropdown "title=test" to become mandatory once "Decision" has been selected in a previous dropdown.

Comment: So you're talking about validation?  Is this on a custom page of yours or on a SharePoint form page?